# Ignorar leitura do primeiro input

Tags: javascript

Como eu ignoro a leitura do primeiro valor de uma array? Eu não quero remover a mesma, so quero na hora de exibir, não apareça a mesma:

Eu ja fiz isso:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.form .form-control').forEach(function (a) {
   console.log(a.value);
});
```

```html
<form class="form">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="Não é pra aparecer">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Teste1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Teste2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Teste3">
</form>
```

O primeiro input como podem ver, é apenas um input do tipo hidden e não quero que o valor dele apareça, mas também não quero que ele seja removido... Alguém me da uma luz?

Obrigado!

Comment: Existe a necessidade de utilizar a classe form-control nesse input? Pois se você não utilizar, ele não entrará no forEach

Comment: Puts, Nathan, KKKKKKKK  as vezes é cada idiotice que faço, obrigado cara!

Comment: Em programação é normal.

Comment: Se quiser por la como resposta, ai marco como aceita!

Comment: Pronto, coloquei um pouco melhor explicado para quem precisar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tirar a classe `form-control` do `<input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="Não é pra aparecer">`, pois assim, ele não será chamado por:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.form .form-control').forEach(function (a) {
   console.log(a.value);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Se quer ignorar o elemento porque ele é "hidden", basta fazer isso no seletor, com `:not([type="hidden"])`.

Ou se quer ignorar o primeiro, mudar para um comando `for` ignorando o primeiro elemento.

Veja abaixo os dois exemplos:

```js
console.log("ignorando hidden");
document.querySelectorAll('.form .form-control:not([type="hidden"]').forEach(function (a) {
   console.log(a.value);
});


console.log("ignorando primeiro elemento");
var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('.form .form-control');
for(var x=1; x<elementos.length;x++) {
  console.log(elementos[x].value);
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="Não é pra aparecer">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Teste1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Teste2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Teste3">
</form>
```